# Is there any handy converter between html odf ooxml and rtf?

Tags: html, rtf, openxml, odf

**Question1**

Is there any lib which can convert between OOXML and HTML,
I mean OOXML2HTML and HTML2OOXML both.

**Question2**

And is there any lib which can convert between ODF and HTML(ODF2HTML HTML2ODF)

**Question3**

and is there any lib which can convert between HTML and RTF(RTF2HTML HTML2RTF)

I want to write a wyswyg online writer, which can edit OOXML ODF, I think I need a good converter first.

Can Any one help?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the opendocument-user mail list of OASIS?

http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=office#feedback

Archive available here: http://lists.oasis-open.org/archives/opendocument-users/

The know all sorts of tools for ODF over there.

:o)

Comment: Thank u jesper!,but the second link only get the following informations201103: by date, thread
201102: by date, thread
201101: by date, thread
201012: by date, thread
201011: by date, thread
201009: by date, thread
201008: by date, thread
201007: by date, thread

Comment: Hi sxingfeng,

The last link points to the public archive of the mail list - in case you were looking to search the archive for your answer. Otherwise you need to subscribe to the list to post a question there.